# Microsoft Excel VBA Error Run-Time 1004 on Application Open Causing Endless Error Loop Preventing Any Use of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

When Excel is opened - no matter the document - there is a run-time error as shown in the picture below[image]

clicking on End does nothing but brings up the same error window again, causing a loop that causes Excel to not be usable. Please advise. Thanks! This is Excel on Mac. I tried re-installing already.

Comment: What addins do you have installed?

Comment: How can I tell? None as far as I am aware of

Comment: Double check under File > Options > Addins.

Comment: The box is preventing any access to anything in Excel - including checking addins

Comment: Please upvote if you are not sure - This is a serious Exel issue I think

Comment: You can run Excel without invoking any installed macros by holding down the control key when clicking on the Excel icon.

Comment: [Start Excel in safe mode for Mac](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-open-MS-Excel-in-safe-mode-on-a-Mac-computer-Excel-freezes-for-2-mins-straight-with-100-CPU-every-45-secs-Everything-I-googled-only-gives-instructions-for-opening-excel-in-safe-mode-using-windows-Can-I-use).

Comment: I am using a Mac - will that still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is posted here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975724/excel-for-mac-error-the-application-microsoft-excel-quit-unexpectedly

Delete entire folder that ends in .office